# Approaches to table partitioning in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

The database I'm working with is currently over 100 GiB and promises to grow much larger over the next year or so.  I'm trying to design a partitioning scheme that will work with my dataset but thus far have failed miserably.  My problem is that queries against this database will typically test the values of multiple columns in this one large table, ending up in result sets that overlap in an unpredictable fashion.

Everyone (the DBAs I'm working with) warns against having tables over a certain size and I've researched and evaluated the solutions I've come across but they all seem to rely on a data characteristic that allows for logical table partitioning.  Unfortunately, I do not see a way to achieve that given the structure of my tables.

Here's the structure of our two main tables to put this into perspective.

```
Table: Case
Columns:
Year
Type
Status
UniqueIdentifier
PrimaryKey
etc.

Table: Case_Participant
Columns:
Case.PrimaryKey
LastName
FirstName
SSN
DLN
OtherUniqueIdentifiers
```

Note that any of the columns above can be used as query parameters.

Comment: You might do better asking this on serverfault.

Comment: Agree with Joel.  I have retaged it.  The talent at ServerFault are expert in this area.

Comment: I was tempted to post it there instead but after reviewing some of the questions there it didn't seem to fit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than guess, measure. Collect statistics of usage ([queries run](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=1d3a4a0d-7e0c-4730-8204-e419218c1efc&displaylang=en)), look at the engine own statistics like [`sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx) and then you make an informed decision: the partition that bests balances data size and gives best affinity for the most often run queries will be a good candidate. Of course you'll have to compromise.

Also don't forget that [partitioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186311(SQL.90).aspx) is per index (where 'table' = one of the indexes), not per table, so the question is not what to partition on, but which indexes to partition or not and what partitioning function to use. Your clustered indexes on the two tables are going to be the most likely candidates obviously (not much sense to partition just a non-clustered index and not partition the clustered one) so, unless you're considering redesign of your clustered keys, the question is really what partitioning function to choose for your clustered indexes.

If I'd venture a guess I'd say that for any data that accumulates over time (like 'cases' with a 'year') the most natural partition is the [sliding window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964122(SQL.90).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you have no other choice you can partition by key module the number of partition tables.
Lets say that you want to partition to 10 tables.
You will define tables:
Case00
Case01
...
Case09

And partition you data by UniqueIdentifier or PrimaryKey module 10 and place each record in the corresponding table (Depending on your unique UniqueIdentifier you might need to start manual allocation of ids).

When performing a query, you will need to run same query on all tables, and use UNION to merge the result set into a single query result.

It's not as good as partitioning the tables based on some logical separation which corresponds to the expected query, but it's better then hitting the size limit of a table.

Comment: Not hitting the table size limit is definitely a goal but I also am trying to preserve query performance.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible thing to look at (before partitioning) is your model.

Are you in a normalized database?  Are there further steps which could improve performance by different choices in the normalization/de-/partial-normalization?  Are there options to transform the data into a Kimball-style dimensional star model which is optimal for reporting/querying?

If you aren't going to drop partitions of the table (sliding window, as mentioned) or treat different partitions differently (you say any columns can be used in the query), I'm not sure what you are trying to get out of the partitioning that you won't already get out of your indexing strategy.

I'm not aware of any table limits on rows.  AFAIK, the number of rows is limited only by available storage.